# Django application doesn't seem to recognize related name?

Tags: django

I have a django app with a User's model that contains a followers field that serves the purpose of containing who follows the user and by using related_name we can get who the User follows. Vice versa type of thing. Printing the User's followers works, but I can't seem to get the followees to work.

views.py

```
followers = User.objects.get(username='bellfrank2').followers.all()
following = User.objects.get(username='bellfrank2').followees.all()

print(followers)
print(following)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name="followees")
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'followees'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation all many to many relationships that are recursive are also symmetrical by default.

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

> When Django processes this model, it identifies that it has a ManyToManyField on itself, and as a result, it doesn’t add a person_set attribute to the Person class. Instead, the ManyToManyField is assumed to be symmetrical – that is, if I am your friend, then you are my friend.

So to, make your field actually create the `followees` attribute you need to set the `symmetrical` attribute to `False`.

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name="followees", symmetrical=False)
```

Comment: Nice! That's good to know. Cleaning up comments now.

Comment: it works, turns out that it was indeed a symmetry issue